# How to copy and rename all .yml.sample files to be .yml in Linux?

Tags: bash

In `bash` I want to copy all `.yml.sample` files in a Git repository (recursively) and rename them to just have a `.yml extension`.

Eg. `test.yml.sample` would be copied to `test.yml`

Here’s as close as I’ve got, but I'm not clear on how to strip `.sample` off the end of the file name when I copy.

```
find . -depth -name "*.yml.sample" -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "${1%/.sample/}"' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
find . -depth -name "*.yml.sample" -exec sh -c 'cp -p "$1" "${1%.yml.sample}.yml"' _ {} \;
```

The first `*.yml.sample` finds the files via `find`. Then after the `-exec` part, the magic happens via `cp` taking the results of that `find` via `$1` and then the file extension for the copied file is set via `${1%.yml.sample}.yml` where `.yml.sample` is the source extension, and `.yml` is the new destination extension.

Note I also added the `-p` attribute to preserve the attributes from the source file to the copied file. You might not need that, but I think it can be helpful when doing copies like this.

And—since this shell logic can be confusing—in terms of the `_ {} \;`, it breaks down as this:

- `_ {}`: As explained in [this answer on the Unix/Linux Stack Exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244027/30848), “The way this works is bash takes the parameters after `-c` as arguments, `_ {}` is needed so that the contents of `{}` is assigned to `$1` not `l`.”
- `\;`: When you run `find` with a `-exec` parameter, everything that happens after that is parsed through a new shell. Meaning the main `find` command runs in one parent shell and stuff after `-exec` runs in another child shell command. If you run it as `_ {} ;`, the child shell command would terminate. So instead, you escape it as `\;` so you get `_ {} \;` which means only the parent sell `find` would interpret that `;` as a “terminate” and thus the paren `find` command can successfully run iterative commands via `-exec` without stopping that child shell command. Read up on [`-exec command ;` here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Comment: That nearly worked but I was getting the following error:

`find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`

.  Updating it as follows worked:

`find . -depth -name "*.yml.sample" -exec sh -c 'cp -p "$1" "${1%.yml.sample}.yml"' _ {} \;`

Comment: @JakeGould thank you so much. I needed this to copy and rename non hd file as hd file for cocos2d. It worked perfectly fine. find . -depth -name "*.png" -exec sh -c 'cp -p "$1" "${1%.png}-hd.png"' _ {} \;

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! One question thou: what is `_ {} \;` for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a tool like `mmv`, to mass rename all the files you need.

```
mmv \*.yml.sample \#1.yml
```

The above line should work...  just make sure to test it first.  Hope this helps!

---

Edit:  If you want to *copy* and rename, all in one step, you can use the `-c` flag.  That will preserve the original file, and will make a copy using the rename mask.

```
mmv -c \*.yml.sample \#1.yml
```

Comment: Plus one for a less verbose example

Comment: For anyone on OSX that has multiple `ext.sample` use brew to install `mmv` and then `mmv -c \*.sample \#1`